# Gauss-Codazzi equation - Riemann tensor on a manifold $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors

Let $\Sigma \subset M$ be a hypersurface.

Gauss-Codazzi equation:

$$^\Sigma \text{Rc}_{ij} =\ ^M \text{Rc}_{ij} -\ ^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j) + H  A_{ij} - A_{il} A^l_j \tag{1}$$
or

$$^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j) =\ ^M \text{Rc}_{ij} -\ ^\Sigma \text{Rc}_{ij} + H  A_{ij} - A_{il} A^l_j \tag{2}$$

where

$^\Sigma \text{Rc}_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor on $\Sigma$

$^M \text{Rm}$ is the Riemann tensor on manifold $M$

$\nu$ is the unit normal vector to $\Sigma$

$H$ is the mean curvature

$A_{ij}$ is the second fundamental form

**Question:**

How to calculate $^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j)$?

Here I have

$$^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j) =\ ^M \text{Rc}^T_{ij} + G(\nu,\nu)g_{ij} \\
^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j) 
 =\ ^MR_{ij}^T + \bigg(\ ^{M}\text{Rc}(\nu,\nu) - \frac{^MR}{2}\  \cdot g(\nu,\nu) \bigg) g_{ij} \tag{3}$$

where $G =\ ^M \text{Rc} - \frac{1}{2}\ ^M \text{Sc} \cdot g$ is the Einstein tensor. Since $g(\nu,\nu) = |\nu|^2=1$, then (3) becomes

$$^M \text{Rm}(\partial_i,\nu,\nu,\partial_j) =\ ^MR_{ij}^T + \bigg(\ ^{M}\text{Rc}(\nu,\nu) - \frac{^MR}{2} \bigg) g_{ij} \tag{4}$$

But I am afraid I am just repeating the equation (2).

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is your progress so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I just added my progress